# ASP.NET markup has two controls, A, then B. Why does B appear first?

Tags: asp.net, user-interface

Here's my full markup:

```
<%@page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Master Pages/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Statistics.aspx.vb" Inherits="Statistics" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="phPageContent" runat="Server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="CaptionLabel"></asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="DefaultDropDown" />
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height="438px" Width="877px" Palette="Bright">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" ChartType="Line" Legend="Legend1" Name="Clicks">
            </asp:Series>
            <asp:Series ChartArea="ChartArea1" ChartType="Line" Legend="Legend1" Name="Conversions">
            </asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                <AxisY Title="Count" TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 10pt">
                </AxisY>
                <AxisX Title="Month" TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 10pt">
                </AxisX>
                <AxisY2 TextOrientation="Rotated270" Title="Commission (USD)" TitleFont="Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt, style=Bold">
                </AxisY2>
            </asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
        <Legends>
            <asp:Legend Name="Legend1" Title="Legend">
                <CellColumns>
                    <asp:LegendCellColumn Name="Column1" Text="#SERIESNAME">
                        <Margins Left="15" Right="15" />
                    </asp:LegendCellColumn>
                    <asp:LegendCellColumn ColumnType="SeriesSymbol" Name="Column2">
                        <Margins Left="15" Right="15" />
                    </asp:LegendCellColumn>
                </CellColumns>
            </asp:Legend>
        </Legends>
        <Titles>
            <asp:Title Font="Microsoft Sans Serif, 12pt" Name="Title1" Text="Monthly Clicks and Conversions ">
            </asp:Title>
        </Titles>
    </asp:Chart>
</asp:Content>
```

And here's how it renders. The code behind simply adds the points.

**Why does the CHART appear AFTER the label and drop down list control if the label appear first in the flow?**

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a CSS phenomenon?

Comment: Please, add the generated html and the corresponding css. This can be due to things being absolutely positioned or floated using css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dropdownlist IS appearing after the chart. If the chart had a border or if you were to add a

tag after the dropdown, this will become more obvious.